# how to call a class on click in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to create a dialog box with yes and no button.,so i used the gui.window and create it a script.,but now i want to call this script on back button click.

**toast.cs**

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 350, 70, 20), "Back ")) 
    { 

    }
}
```

**dialog.cs**

```
public class dialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUIStyle mystyle;
    public  Rect windowRect = new Rect (150, 80, 200, 100) ;

    public  void OnGUI ()
    {
        windowRect = GUI.Window (0, windowRect, WindowFunction, "Save !!!");
    }

    public  void WindowFunction (int windowID) 
    {
         GUI.Label( new Rect( 40, 40, 120, 50 ), "Do you want to save ?? ",mystyle  );
       if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 70, 70, 20), "Yes ")) 
       { 
           Application.LoadLevel("Settings");
       }

       if (GUI.Button (new Rect (120, 70, 70, 20), "No ")) 
       { 
           Application.LoadLevel("Settings");   
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to do. I have an idea, but I don't want to answer unless I am sure what your question is.

Comment: @  FunctionR on button click i want to create an dialog box,in which we have two buttons "yes" and "no"..and on yes user can save the game state.on no user can be exit to main menu. so i create a dialog box with the help of GUI Window,it is working perfectly fine in seprate script.,but i want to call it on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
//This will add the dialog, so, And now the window will show up!
gameObject.AddComponent<dialog>();
```

Since your dialog script is a MonoBehaviour, you must add it to a object to display it.

and, you must check the "No" option, it's giving the same result as "Yes" :P

you can do a

```
//This will remove the dialog, so, I will no longer see the window =)
gameObject.RemoveComponent<dialog>();
```

Is that what you want? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**toast.cs**

```
void OnGUI() {
       if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 350, 70, 20), "Back ")) 
       { 
            new dialog().OpenGUI();
       }
}
```

**dialog.cs**

```
public class dialog : MonoBehaviour {
    public GUIStyle mystyle;
    public  Rect windowRect = new Rect (150, 80, 200, 100) ;

    public  void OnGUI () {
       OpenGUI();
    }

    public void OpenGUI(){
       windowRect = GUI.Window (0, windowRect, WindowFunction, "Save !!!");
    }

    public  void WindowFunction (int windowID) {
         GUI.Label( new Rect( 40, 40, 120, 50 ), "Do you want to save ?? ",mystyle  );
       if (GUI.Button (new Rect (10, 70, 70, 20), "Yes ")) 
       { 
         Application.LoadLevel("Settings");
       }

       if (GUI.Button (new Rect (120, 70, 70, 20), "No ")) 
       { 
         Application.LoadLevel("Settings");   
       }
    }

 }
```

This is only common sense though, you might want to check out [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) they will be able to help out way more than here in StackOverflow

Comment: @ Tzah Mama thanks for the suggestion and sry but this new dialog().OpenGUI(); can't be used. and i thought this place is  for all sorts of queries that's why i asked